# data structure for grouping children without parents

Tags: mysql, database-design, mariadb, schema

I have a list of name

```
ID    Name
1     John Doe
2     J. Doe
3     John Doe
4     John Doe
```

With different methods, I check which names are the same person by checking their actions. For example, in step 1 I find ID 1-3 are one person and ID 4 another person.

Obviously, I need to give each person an ID to group them

```
ID    Name        PersonID
1     John Doe    1
2     J. Doe      1
3     John Doe    1
4     John Doe    2
```

In step 2, I find ID 2 and 4 are also the same person (making ID 1-4 the same person). How should I update the parent?

I think I should create PersonID at the last stage. I need a temporary schema to group the records.

Do you any suggestions for a schema to gradually update the same persons.

Answer (score 1):

> In step 2, I find ID 2 and 4 are also the same person (making ID 1-4 the same person). How should I update the parent?

For example, it can be

```sql
SET @dup1 := 2;
SET @dup2 := 4;

UPDATE test t0
JOIN test t1
JOIN test t2
SET t0.PersonID = t1.PersonID
WHERE t1.id = @dup1
  AND t2.id = @dup2
  AND t0.PersonID IN (t1.PersonID, t2.PersonID);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=825e1c58b5e7fae31eca9485fa4124ce

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to have 2 helper tables with following structure

```
CREATE TABLE NewPersons(
ID INT Identity, 
Name VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE PersonMappings(
NewPersonsID INT, 
PersonID INT
)
```

After 1st step you insert 1 row into `NewPersons` table with the correct name that you want to use. For example

```
ID          Name
----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           John Doe
```

And 3 rows into PersonMappings table which will indicate that the new created person is mapped to Persons with ids 1, 2 and 3.

```
NewPersonID PersonID
----------- -----------
1           1
1           2
1           3
```

After you find that person id 2 and 4 are the same, you need to search this ids in your mapping table, and insert that personID with corresponding NewPersonID pair.

```
SELECT NewPersonID
FROM PersonMappings
WHERE PersonID = 2
```

You get `NewPersonID = 1` from this query and Insert `(1, 4)` pair into `PersonMappings` table